# Remove all formatting after the div

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Is there a way to keep all text formatting withing a `<div></div>` tag, without having any un-closed tags spill over to the rest of the page?

I have a `repeater` control that displays content from a `database` onto a standard `label` within a `<div>`. To reduce space costs, I formatted the string to *1000 characters*. This unfortunately cuts off any closing tags, and causes the rest of the page to get effected.

I need to get a way to either render the `<div>`'s last, or force the tags to close.
I dont thing the `htmlAgilityPack` will work with this.

I have no idea how to do this, or where  to start, so I have no code to display. Could anyone please point me to the right direction.

Comment: If you don't want _any_ formatting for the enclosed text fragment, just use the `innerText` property.

Comment: I do want formatting for the text within the `<div>`. I just need the formatting to stay in the `<div>`, and not leak out if it is unclosed.

Comment: truncate your HTML, iterate over it in tokens, if token is an opening tag, push it in a stack. On encountering a closing tag, pop a tag (validate if you like) from the stack. When the strings end, pop all remaining tags one by one, and append corresponding closing tag to the string. That's the idea

Comment: @Ejay I thought I had to do something like that from the beginning. I think I was just hoping for some awesome `html` standard that simply worked. :)

Comment: What language is supported here ? You don't get content from DB, subtring to 1000 characters manually, right?

Comment: Forgot to add that, all this is in C# -> MsSql 2012. The text is inserted into the DB in the `content`, along with the 1000 characters in the same row, in the `preview` column. The `Repeater` displays the `preview`, whiles clicking on `read more` will take you to a page displaying the `content`.

Comment: You know what, I was about to post a PHP solution for making truncated HTML valid. Bad timing for an edit :D

Comment: @NewAmbition: If I understand correctly, do you want to detect & add any closing html tags which got truncated? Is jQuery viable solution for you?

Comment: @Ejay haha damn :/ Well - At least youre on the ball with this one :D

Comment: @Daredev Yeah, I basically want to do that. I am working on a C# method to sort it out now, which I'll post up for editing. JQuery is a valid option, but I dont want to really load all the info, then only edit it. Also, it needs to work in a `Repeater`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) can indeed close tags automatically. For example, this code

```
string html = "<div>hello<b>bold<i>and italic";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

Will output this:

```
<div>hello<b>bold<i>and italic</i></b></div>
```

Comment: I cant save to a stream.. Need to add it to the DB. _ I really need to clue myself up on this.

Comment: @NewAmbition - doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml contains the corresponding string if you need it as a string, that was just a Console Application sample.

Comment: Thanks man. This, as obvious as it should of been to me, seems much better :D

Answer (score 0):

I've created a method to check the string, and close the tags. I will update with any further recommendations for the code.

```
    public string FormatClosingTags(string origionalText)
    {
        string manipulate = origionalText;

        // Get the tags away from the words.
        manipulate = manipulate.Replace(">", "> ");
        manipulate = manipulate.Replace("<", " <");

        // Now that the tags are alone and weak, split them up!
        string[] tags = manipulate.Split(' ');

        // Create holding cells to sibigate the tags.
        List<string> openingTags = new List<string>();
        List<string> closingTags = new List<string>();

        // Create a marshal to hold the subjugated tags.
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        // Find all those tags!
        foreach (string s in tags)
        {
            // Make sure its only the women and children
            if ((s.Contains("<") || s.Contains(">")) && (!s.Contains("</")))
            {
                openingTags.Add(s);
            }
            // While keeping the males to themsleves
            else if ((s.Contains("<") || s.Contains(">")) && (s.Contains("</")))
            {
                closingTags.Add(s);
            }
        }


        // Get one of those harsh ladies with a clipboard and make her count all the men
        int counter = closingTags.Count;

        // Destroy all the females that have a male
        openingTags.RemoveRange(0, counter);

        // Find the rest of the lonely women
        foreach (string open in openingTags)
        {
            // CONVERT THEM TO MEN - add them to the marshal's list
            output.Append(open.Replace("<", "</"));
        }

        return origionalText + output;
    }
```